# Does the Season Pass include preorder bonuses like the Mechromancer class?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have pre-ordered Borderlands 2, giving me the Mechromancer class for free. The season Pass that will come out soon after release will consists of 4 DLC packs. Does the Mechromancer class DLC count as 1 of those DLC packs?

Comment: Aren't questions regarding unreleased games considered off topic?

Comment: The faq is intended more as a guide to asking questions more than a blanket rule for bans - arqade prefers case-by-case if possible. Yes, as per the faq, questions cannot be about "Speculation of the future of the industry and of upcoming releases". However, in this case the pre-order for Borderlands 2 has been open for purchase and information about its exclusive features are well-known. They promised that Mechromancer access would be exclusive to pre-orders, and legally if they changed that they would be false advertising to people who have already paid money. No speculation necessary.

Comment: Mechromancer is now available via DLC, FYI @toNyldaS.

Comment: @EBongo Yeah, so much for that ._.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The Mechromancer character class and other preorder items are not included in the Borderlands 2 Season Pass.

[Joystiq](http://www.joystiq.com/2012/08/30/borderlands-2-season-pass-announced-all-4-dlc-for-30/)

Answer (score 1):

"Ursprungligen skrivet av TrentTheWanderer:
The big issue here is that for a brief period of time the Mechromancer statement reported that the Season Pass would award the character. Reading, unfortunately, was the cause of the miscommunication in the first place, and both in Europe and the U.S. there are trade laws stating that point-of-sale product discriptions must match the delivered product. That means that for those people who purchased the Season Pass while the Mechromancer was stated as being included bought access to that content, and as such should currently have access.

If the developers really wanted the season pass not to include Mechromancer, they should have explained it that way to the Steam retailer more clearly to prevent the miscommunication."
So...Gearbox might change their mind.